# Is it possbile to create redis cache with both Geo replica and Persistence?

Tags: azure, azure-redis-cache

On Azure portal, the Geo-replication is disabled if the Data persistence is enabled. why?

Is it possbile to create redis cache with both Geo replica and Persistence?

Answer (score 0):

Below are the requirements for enabling geo-replication for Azure Redis Cache. The last item in the list confirms what you are seeing. Redis Cache data persistence requires a Storage Account in the same region as the instance being persisted. Geo-Replication does not have this requirement, and it is recommended that each instance be deployed in separate regions. Also, as part of the Geo-Replication, the primary Redis instance is being synched to the secondary. In effect, data persistence is single server functionality.

There are some prerequisites that must be met before geo-replication can be configured:

- The caches must be in the same subscription
- The secondary cache must be either the same pricing tier or a larger pricing tier than the primary linked cache
- If the primary cache is clustered, the secondary cache must also be clustered with the same number of shards
- The caches must both be running
- **Redis persistence must not be enabled for either cache**